# Can I define the State in single step

Tags: flutter

In `Flutter` the `StatefulWidget` widget is required to be defined in 2 steps, first define a class the extends the `StatefulWidget` like:

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => new _CounterState();
}
```

Then a class that extends the `State` of the previous one, like:

```
class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      ++_counter;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(children: <Widget>[
      ...
    ]);
  }
}
```

Is not there a way that I define the `createState()` within the `StatefulWidget` class without a need to define a separate `State` class

I tried starting by this, but could not know what to do next

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return ????
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not supposed to work. The Widget is reused when the state changes. To make this work they have to be 2 classes.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is : No you can't.

But why ? In fact it's fairly simple to understand.
In flutter, everytimes you want to use a widget you do `new MyWidget(...)`. Notice the word *new*. It means you instantiate a new object everytimes you update your widget tree. But it also means that the widget will get a nice *hard reset* everytimes you update. Preventing you from storing any mutable data inside widgets.

---

*But then, how do stateful widgets work ?*

See that `createState` of the first part ? On the first instantiation of your widget, it will be called. 
And then it will be cached inside one of the lower layer.

So that next time you instantiate your widget, the state will instead be fetched from cache and therefore preserve it's custom values.